# Why is an integer shown on the console when an object reference is logged there?

Tags: javascript, console, object-literal

I am working on a app that makes use of object literals to represent groups, topics, and tasks.  There is also an object literal that handles command input from the app's "command-line interface".

When the user clicks on a topic, the command object sets its `obj` property to refer to the object that represents what was clicked on.  That is: the user clicks a group title, and now `command.obj` represents the group object.

The function below resides in the `command` object literal and shows how `this.obj` is set.  It is called when an element is clicked, that element is the `obj` var passed in to the function:

```
/* defines taxonomy and obj of clicked element */
set_taxonomy: function(obj){
    if( $(obj).hasClass('group-title') ){
        this.taxonomy = $.trim('group');
        this.obj = group;
        }
    else if($(obj).hasClass('topic-title') ){
        this.taxonomy = $.trim('topic');
        this.obj = topic;
        }
    else if( $(obj).hasClass('task') ){ 
        this.taxonomy = $.trim('task');
        this.obj = task;
        }

    console.log(this.obj);

    this.set_commands();

},
```

`group, topic, and title` are object literals that are loaded automatically.
When topics and titles are clicked, `console.log(this.obj)` prints out `object` with all the respective properties and functions.

**Clicking on a group shows the number `3`.**

What does the 3 mean?

See example of working topic object : http://[pastebin.com/NEmKHdzc](http://pastebin.com/NEmKHdzc)

See example of non-working group object : http://pastebin.com/ezPghLbM

Comment: Maybe that class has a "toString" function defined.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b9u68/) is a jsfiddle demonstrating that  there's nothing funny about your "group" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure group is being set properly?  Try `console.log(group)` in the first if statement.  If you get 3, I would double-check (with more `console.log` calls) that you are setting group properly in the first place.

Comment: Face-slap!  I innocently used 'group' in a for statement somewhere else.  Today's lesson is apparently on variable scope.  Thanks for the encouragement to log(group) elsewhere.  I found that the desired group object existed on page load, then was == 3 later on.  A search and replace found where I broke it.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW: the 3 came from the last array index in the for loop that was resetting 'group'.

Comment: Are you declaring your variables with `var`?  Assuming that the reuse of group was in its own function (not the function where group is defined or used), using `var group` at the top should solve the issue.   In general, using `var` is a good practice - there is nothing more fun than realizing that your error is from calling a function and having it overwrite a variable you care about.

Comment: @retort, yeah, that's just about what happened

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure group is an object literal? There's not enough information to assume group is not actually equal to 3.

```
console.log(group === 3);
```

Comment: `console.log(group === 3);` prints `false`. `console.log(group == 3);` however prints `true`

Comment: Are you declaring those vars? As in, `var group = {};` ? Perhaps the (global) group var is being redefined somewhere else in your application.